# Converting voice to text using Phone-Gap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I need to make an iPhone application that read sound from microphone and convert it to text, is possible to do using phoneGap.

Thanks,
Companion

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet possible with phonegap.
As you will need to stream the audio.
This streaming is in the roadmap tough.